# i can access the element(input tag) but not its content for neither textContent nor innerText

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events

```html
 <div class="container">
    <input id="word1" type="text"  placeholder="Enter First Word"><br>
    <input  id="submit1" type="submit" name="submit" value="check">
   </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let word1 = document.getElementById('word1');
        let submit = document.getElementById('submit1');

         function display(){
            alert(word1.textContent);
            alert(word1.innerText);
            alert(word1);
            }
        
        submit.addEventListener('click',display,false);
    </script>
```

the browser alerts with empty string for both textContent and innerText and i don't know why is this happening

Comment: input's have no content

Comment: why can't it access what i wrote in input box from browser?

Comment: @Shubham
Just a typo(maybe).
HTML Input ID: `submit`, you selected: `submit1`  that not exists!!

Comment: input's can have a value - here's some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) for `<input>` ... note the "technical summary" that states "Permitted Content" as "none" since it's an "empty element"

Comment: @ChangAlex i have changed it still same results

Comment: You're not reading the comments that actually help then

Comment: If you want to get input value please use .value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input doesn't have `textContent`, if you want get it's value, you need to go with `input.value`.

```html
<div class="container">
    <input id="word1" type="text"  placeholder="Enter First Word"><br>
    <input  id="submit1" type="submit" name="submit" value="check">
   </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let word1 = document.getElementById('word1');
        let submit = document.getElementById('submit1');

         function display(){
            alert(word1.value);
            }
        
        submit.addEventListener('click',display,false);
    </script>
```

Comment: and now i feel stupid. thanks btw

Comment: Never mind, you are welcome.